# There will be support for Kaleo Workflow on Liferay 7?

Tags: liferay

I've been using the Kaleo Workflow on Liferay 6.2 and I've been searching for support of this plugin on Liferay7. Anyone knows if it will be supported or evolved on this version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's already contained in the current Version 7 alpha 3 download. Just download that version, it's contained in there. As it's now an OSGi plugin, you won't find it as a separate web application, but it's in the OSGi folder, among a huge load of other plugins and modules.

Comment: I've verified it. But still wanna know if the development of kaleo will continue on the next version. Help?

Comment: Do you mean development of new features or keeping it around? It will be in 7, obviously. Probably with roughly the functionality you currently see. It's to early to predict further, I don't expect it to go away though